# Moving site template from wss to sharpoint foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, wss

I am migrating my site from WSS to SharePoint Foundation but I have few site templates in the WSS version which I want to know how to move the .stp file to SharePoint Foundation ?

Let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://salaudeen.blogspot.in/2011/09/migrating-sharepoint-2007-sitelist.html

check this url may be it helps you.

Comment: This is the way to do it without too much more effort, personally I had to do this for a bit of a manual migration I undertook but to be honest the caledars were a mess and certain things don't render properly - the answer is that stp files are not supported in 2010 so if they are just templates then they will need to be re-created from scratch in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Support for migration of custom templates is a challenge since these templates reside in the database, and tampering with them is prohibited. In order to support these kind of templates,our migration tool, Tzunami Deployer was implemented with an ability to read the templates from a local or shared File System folder. It uses an external XML file to map template names to (the matching) .stp files that were uploaded to SharePoint. We simplified the creation of the template mapping XML file by providing the TemplateXmlTool.

If you're interested in trying a free evaluation of our software, visit our website at www.tzunami.com